# Filter functions for @Input() 's not filtering to children properly?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

Q: Why aren't my filter functions updating the children when the main source of data is modified?

I have an array of objects that gets divvied between several child components. Each of the child components takes in an input in the template that is just a .filter() of the array of data, depending on what that child needs.

Namely a solution to make it so there is one source of data that I can update values of when need be that automatically gets passed to all the children without the need for a billion functions everywhere

Problem is, however, it doesn't seem like my functions are filtering after the value in question is updated? I can verify that the central source of data got updated.

Log here below is the new value, the old value, and the value at the index once it is replaced, which should and is the same as the second value (See the **unread count** property in this example)

[image: console log of the initial value, the replacement, and the replaced value within the main array]

Main source of data is gotten with a behavior subject in a service

```js
    /* -- Data subscribes -- */
    // All chats
    this.ChatService.allChats.subscribe((historyArray: Array<MessageHistory>) => {
      this.allChats = historyArray;
    });
```

Example filter function

```js
  public sortByAssignmentStatus(assignmentStatus: AssignmentStatus)
  {
    return this.allChats.filter((history: MessageHistory) => {
      return history.assignmentStatus.assignmentStatusID == assignmentStatus.assignmentStatusID;
    });
  }
```

In template

```html
      <mat-card class="infoCard" *ngFor="let assignmentStatus of assignmentStatuses">
        <mat-card-content class="scrollDiv scrollbar scrollbar-primary tableContentMaxHeight">
          <app-small-loading-spin *ngIf="gettingAllChats"></app-small-loading-spin>
          <app-chat-histories *ngIf="!gettingAllChats"
            [histories]="sortByAssignmentStatus(assignmentStatus)" <---This is where the function is---
            (chatSelectedEvent)="openSelectedChat($event)">
          </app-chat-histories>
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that sortByAssignmentStatus doesn't "run" everytime allchats changes. Angular can't magically know which methods you intend to "watch" and run everytime data changes and which ones are fine being static. But luckily, they do provide a mechanism to do exactly that. Pipes.

You need to change sortByAssignmentStatus to a pipe. For example :

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'sortByAssignmentStatus'
})
export class SortByAssignmentStatusPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any, assignmentStatus : AssignmentStatus): any {
   return value.filter((history: MessageHistory) => {
      return history.assignmentStatus.assignmentStatusID == assignmentStatus.assignmentStatusID;
    });
  }
}
```

And then you can use it like so :

```
<app-chat-histories *ngIf="!gettingAllChats"
        [histories]="allChats|sortByAssignmentStatus:assignmentStatus"
        (chatSelectedEvent)="openSelectedChat($event)">
 </app-chat-histories>
```

Note that this only works if the actual reference of allChats changes (Which is happening because you are resetting the entire array when you call the chat service. If this is modified in another way (e.g. You remove items), then you would have to look at Impure pipes (https://tutorialsforangular.com/2020/02/11/understanding-pure-vs-impure-pipes-in-angular/)